# XML Post Connection Reset Error

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am posting a xml/cxml document to a url online. When I post it I get error "Connection Was Reset". I wanted to post the code to make sure their was no mistake being made.
stXML is the xml document.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stXML);

        req.Method = "POST";

        req.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;

        // req.ContentType = "text/XML-urlencoded";

        Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();

        requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);

        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default);

        string strRet = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

        Response.Write(strRet);

        Response.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there's an issue with your headers.
I would avoid the added complexity of using HttpWebRequest and just use System.Net.WebClient.

```
string response = new WebClient().UploadString(uri, stXML);
```